# URL rewrite: rewrite website name php

Tags: php, url

I didn' try anything.
But i want to clear one question.
I have a link www.abc.com/meeting/
Is it possible to rewrite abc to my own words
eg: www.myown.com/meeting/

Is it possible with URL rewriting

Comment: add more explanation on you question

Comment: @Ajeet Kumar i want to know is it possible to change the abc to myown in my example link without change the website address

Comment: Yes its possible via htaccess you can use .htaccess file to rewrite your url/domain name

Comment: @Ajeet Kumar if  you don' mind please give me example ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Apache have enabled option `Rewrite mode`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^abc.com/meeting/.*$ http://www.myown.com/meeting/ [R=301,L]
```

Use this code in filename as `.htaccess` save this file in your root folder
allow .htaccess file in your server. In xampp it bydefault activated

Comment: thanks @Ajeet Kumar. Another doubt. I have one parameter to the function meeting. is it create any problem ie, abc.com/meeting/1

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal You can remove this meting pareameter from rewirting mode like this `RewriteRule ^abc.com/.*$ http://www.myown.com/ [R=301,L]`. It can be create problem if it doesn't find meeting

Answer (score 3):

This is the dynamic version which will redirect all the url to specified domain. So www.abc.com/* will be redirected to www.myown.com/*

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.abc.com/.$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myown.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```